# Missing, config.json file or invalid json syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitor

I keep getting this error trying to run this script 
not sure why. I am assuming something in the syntax does not correlate with the version of node I am running

I am running it via

```
npm start
```

I have the config file in the same file and it is running monitor.js.
Version of node is 4.1.2
Name of config file is config.json

```html
{
    "interval": 60000,
    "serverPort": 1337,
    "autoRetryOnCrash": true,
    "noImageURL": "http://i.imgur.com/MdsG0Po.png",
    "notify": {
        "new": false,
        "restocks": false,
        "keywords": true
    },
    "slackBot": {
        "active": false,
        "token": "token goes here",
        "channel": "monitor",
        "settings": {
            "username": "ShopifyMonitor",
            "icon_url": "http://i.imgur.com/zks3PoZ.png"
        }
    },
    "twitter": {
        "active": false,
        "encodeImages": false,
        "consumer_key": "",
        "consumer_secret": " ",
        "access_token": "",
        "access_token_secret": ""
    },
    "sites": [
        "https://shop-usa.palaceskateboards.com/sitemap_products_1.xml",
        "http://kithnyc.com/sitemap_products_1.xml"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "nmd",
        "ultraboost",
        "yeezy"
    ]
}
```

[Folder containing both monitor.js and config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCBq6.png) 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2ib.png)

Comment: `run this script` - which script? without seeing **HOW** you're reading `config.json` can only guess that you're doing it wrong

Comment: I am running the monitor script via node monitor

Comment: `the monitor script` - what does it look like? as I said, without seeing HOW you're reading `config.json` can only guess that you're doing it wrong ... i.e. can you post the relevant **code** that **loads** `config.json`

Comment: `function loadFile() { try { var configuration = require('./config.json'); } catch (e) { api.log('error', 'Missing, config.json file or invalid json syntax.') return process.exit() } } `

Comment: Paste your json into [this validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), it will tell you what's wrong.